# .NET Core Worker service host as a Windows Services (using Coravel for task scheduling)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I have created a worker service to schedule a task using Coravel is a .NET Standard library and it is working as expected. I want to host the same as a windows service.

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddScheduler();
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); //background service
                }
```

But i am using Corvel Invocable so is there any way i can achieve the same to host as a windows service? like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            host.Services.UseScheduler(scheduler =>
            {
                scheduler.Schedule<CsvGenerationInvocable>().EveryMinute();
            });
            host.Run();
        }



public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddScheduler();
                    services.AddHostedService<CsvGenerationInvocable>(); // Error no implicit conversion to IHostedService
                 }
```

Corval Invokable :

```
 public class CsvGenerationInvocable : IInvocable
        {
public async Task Invoke()
        {
           //Logic
        }
        }
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this somehow?

Comment: @Asunez No I did not found any solution for this so I created a windows service in .net core instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also inherit Background service to your Invokable class.

```
 public class CsvGenerationInvocable : BackgroundService, IInvocable
        {
public async Task Invoke()
        {
           //Logic
        }
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example illustrating how Coravel can be used to implement a Windows service based on the 'Worker Service' template.

https://github.com/AlanPBourke/CoravelWindowsService